# Let $M \ge 0$ be such that $\int_E f_n \le M$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$. Show that $\int_E f \le M$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of non-negative measurable functions that converges to $f$ pointwise on $E$. Let $M \ge 0$ be such that $\int_E f_n \le M$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$. Show that $\int_E f \le M$.

From a hint I got that since $\int_{E} f_n \le M$, then $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_E f_n \le M.$$ Now using Fatou's lemma I have that $$\int_E f < \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_E f_n \le M \implies \int_E f \le M.$$

My question is that what is the motivation for $\int_{E} f_n \le M$ implying that $\liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_E f_n \le M$? Also how is this true? I couldn't find any result like this on Royden's book where this problem originates from.

Comment: The liminf result is general, having nothing to do with integrals. If $a_n\leq M$ for all $n,$ then $\liminf a_n\leq M.$

Comment: In your case, $$a_n=\int_E f_n.$$

Comment: This seems obvious since if $a_n \le M$ for any $n$, then $\sup_{n \ge 1} \inf_{k \ge n} a_n \le M$, but what's the motivation for this here?

Comment: We actually get a stronger result, $$\limsup a_n\leq M.$$ Since $\limsup\geq\liminf,$ the liminf result follows. Not sure I can explain it more clearly intuitively. You might want to review the geomtric meaning of $\limsup$ and $\liminf,$ which is hard to express here. Think of sequences that do not converge but have finite $\limsup$ and $\liminf.$

Comment: Another way to define $\liminf$ for bounded sequences is to consider all the limit points of the sequence. Then $\liminf$ is the infimum of the limit points, while $\limsup$ is the supremes of the limit points. (This works for unbounded sequences, too, but you need to consider a topology on $[-\infty,+\infty].$)

Comment: Perhaps I was a bit unclear. I meant to ask about the motivation to even consider the $\liminf$ in the first place from $\int_{E} f_n \le M$. It seems that this would have only came to my mind if I remembered Fatou's lemma and the connections between it and $\liminf$.